# Changing text depending on preexisting conditions

Tags: c++

I have a list of buildings that are only shown to the player if they are not built, how do I change the text?

```
 cout<<"These building have not been built yet:"<<
endl<<"1.Bakery(costs 50 wood)"<<
endl<<"2.Blacksmith (costs 50 stone)"<<
endl<<"3.Bazaar(Costs 50 Wood)";
```

How do I remove some of the text? I've tried if statements like this:

```
if(bakery){
 cout<<"These buildings have not been built yet:"<<
endl<<"2.Blacksmith (costs 50 stone)"<<
endl<<"3.Bazaar(Costs 50 Wood)";
}
else if(blacksmith){
cout<<"These building have not been built yet:"<<
endl<<"1.Bakery(costs 50 wood)"<<
endl<<"3.Bazaar(Costs 50 Wood)";
}
else if(bazaar){
cout<<"These building have not been built yet:"<<
endl<<"1.Bakery(costs 50 wood)"<<
endl<<"2.Blacksmith(Costs 50 Stone)";
}
```

And then mixed of all them like this:

```
else if(bakery && blacksmith){
cout<<endl<<"3.Bazaar(Costs 50 Wood)";
}
```

And so on... but that seems very unoptimal, how do I fix it?

Comment: Invert the logic: `if (!bakery) { cout << "1.Bakery(costs 50 wood)" << endl;}`, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why is `bakery` an indication that _blacksmith_ and _bazaar_ have not been built? Why is `blacksmith` and indication of that _bakery_ and _bazaar_ have not been built etc.? It seems backwards.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, it's supposed to show the buildings that have NOT been built, the ones that have appear in a different menu,

Comment: And building on what @JohnnyMopp suggests, consider some kind of container for your buildings that you can iterate over in a loop instead of separate unbundled variables for each building type. `for(auto buildingType : buildings) { if !buildingType.isBuilt() { cout << ... ; } }` or similar.

Comment: @DaugirdasPelanis Right but as written if `bakery` is built, _regardless of whether or not the other two are built_, it will print that the black smith and bazaar have not been built. The line is `if(bakery)`, not `if(bakery && !blacksmith && !bazaar)`.

Comment: I feel that we all need to come to an agreement that if we want to know if the **bakery** has been built or not, we should only inspect the variable named `bakery`.  This seems to be an issue of general logic.  @DaugirdasPelanis, do you agree?

Comment: @NathanPierson, oh yeah I understand that but still, rewriting that so many times seems very unnecessary, hence the question

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yeah, that works, thank you